# Performing inference in Tensorflow with multiple graphs on same GPU parallely

Tags: python, tensorflow

I created 2 tf.graph() (loaded the same frozen model) from different threads, which seem to happen based on the different tf.graph object address that I see in each thread. When I tried to run inference on these 2 graphs parallely using the same GPU, I feel it is running like a sequential pipeline.

This is based on the GPU memory & utilization stats and also the time taken. ie, A single graph would consume 7GB of GPU memory and utilize ~15% of compute. With 2 graphs running parallely I would expect to use twice the GPU memory and increased compute, but that doesn't seem to happen.

Comment: Running two models on the same GPU in parallel usually results in overall slow-down rather than a speed-up. Frameworks like TensorFlow/PyTorch make an assumption that they have entire GPU to themselves and perform poorly otherwise

Comment: Thanks! Since I am doing just inference, GPU resource utilization (compute & memory) is under utilized with single graph. So is batching the only way to increase the resource utilization?

Comment: It's common to get low resource utilization due to some bottleneck. IE, you are using some operation which is not implemented on GPU, so your model is waiting on cpu/gpu copies. The solution is to refactor model to remove this copy, rather than running multiple models in parallel